# PowerMockito mock private methods in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to mock a private method inside my class under test which is as below.

```java
public String processPayment(...) {
    //some lines
    privateMethod(...);
    return "";
}

private Object privateMethod(...) {
    //some lines
    return someObject;
}
```

Now I need to test `processPayment` method and mock `privateMethod`.

I tried creating spy of the above class, but the method gets called when I do below

```java
final DeviceCheckoutServiceImpl spyDeviceCheckoutService = spy(injectedMockBeanOfAboveClass); //@InjectMock in test class
PowerMockito.doReturn(null).when(spyDeviceCheckoutService, "privateMethod", ArgumentMatchers.anyMap()); //method gets called here
spyDeviceCheckoutService.processPayment(...); //private method isn't mocked somehow, and gets called here too
```

The `privateMethod` gets called on the 2nd line itself.
Also, `the privateMethod` isn't mocked.

Maybe I am creating the spy object in a wrong way? Can't do `spy(new DeviceCheckoutServiceImpl());` as it needs bean instantiation.

Powermockito version:

```java
compile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.0'
compile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.0'
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the test class we will call the spy() method of `org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito` by passing the reference to the class that needs to be tested:

```
MockPrivateMethodExample spy = PowerMockito.spy(mockPrivateMethodExample);
```

Then we define what we want to do when this particular private method is called.

```
PowerMockito.doReturn("Test").when(spy, {$methodName});
```

MockPrivateMethodExample.java

```
public class MockPrivateMethodExample {

  public String getDetails() {
    return "Mock private method example: " + iAmPrivate();
  }

  private String iAmPrivate() {
    return new Date().toString();
  }
}
```

MockPrivateMethodTest.java

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MockPrivateMethodExample.class)
public class MockPrivateMethodTest {

  private MockPrivateMethodExample mockPrivateMethodExample;

  // This is the name of the private method which we want to mock
  private static final String METHOD = "iAmPrivate";

  @Test
  public void testPrivateMethod() throws Exception {
    mockPrivateMethodExample = new MockPrivateMethodExample();

    MockPrivateMethodExample spy = PowerMockito.spy(mockPrivateMethodExample);
    PowerMockito.doReturn("Test").when(spy, METHOD);
    String value = spy.getDetails();

    Assert.assertEquals(value, "Mock private method example: Test");
    PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(spy, Mockito.times(1)).invoke(METHOD);
  }
}
```

More details here: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-mock-private-method-example-with-powermock/

Comment: already tried. The method gets called whenever I do `PowerMockito.doReturn("Test").when(spy, METHOD);` , plus, the method doesn't get mocked. :-/

Comment: @PraveenKamath Could you please mark the answer as helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Issue solved!
Had forgot to add `@PrepareForTest(DeviceCheckoutServiceImpl.class)` on the test class.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito introduced `AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo` to support spying on Spring proxies and other such things:

Check out this issue: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/529#issuecomment-239494581

> So instead of `spy(proxy)` use `mock(TestSubject.class,
>   delegatesTo(springProxy))`.
>
> However if annotations are need to read, then you'll need mockito 2
>   beta. Because mockito 1.x uses CGLIB which doesn't copies annotations
>   on the mockito subclass. Mockito 2 uses the great bytebuddy.

Comment: Found the issue. Didn't add `@PrepareForTest(DeviceCheckoutServiceImpl.class)` on the test class.